# $3$-Sylow subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{F}_3)$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Find  a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{F}_3)$.
>
> For $n=3$, how many elements are there in the center of this subgroup?

I tried to understand the order of the $3$-Sylow subgroups, but since we have a general $n$, I couldn't get to anything specific( I know the formula for $|SL(n, \mathbb{F}_3)|$).

Without understanding the order of that sylow subgroup, I can't move any further, as that is the most basic assumption to continue, unless I don't see something.

Any ideas?

Comment: The upper unitriangular matrices form a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm SL}(n,p)$ for any $n \ge 1$ and any prime $p$. That should enable you to work out its order. Its centre has the same order for all $n$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\left|SL(3,\Bbb F_3)\right|=\frac1{3-1}(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-3^2)=13\cdot24\cdot18=3^3\cdot2^4\cdot13\cdot$$

and thus you need a subgroup of order $\;3^3=27\;$ (**any** such subgroup. Why?).

Check the following:

$$H:=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&b\\
0&1&c\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\;|\; a,b, c\in\Bbb F_3\;\right\}$$

Comment: The assumption of $n=3$ is for the second question only.

Comment: @ChikChak It doesn't matter: generalize the above and work on it.

Comment: Ho w? As the first thing you did, is calculating assuming some $n$.

Comment: You need to calculate the order of $SL(n, \mathbb{F_3})$ for a general $n$. Start from calculating the order of $GL(n, \mathbb{F_3})$.

Comment: I know it is $ \frac{(3^n-1)(3^n-3)...(3^n-3^{n-1})}{3-1}$, as I said I know the formula

Comment: Correct. So how many times can you divide it by $3$? $3$ doesn't divide $(3^n-1)$ at all, divides $(3^n-3)$ one time, divides $(3^n-3^2)$ twice, and so on. Hence you get that the order of the 3-Sylow subgroups are $3^{1+2+3+...+(n-1)}$. As for really finding a Sylow subgroup-yes, you have to guess here, but there are reasons to think about diagonal matrices because we don't know too much subgroups of $SL(n, \mathbb{F_3})$.